# How do I install ChomiumOS and run it as a separate X ession?

Tags: xorg, lightdm, chroot, chromeos

I'm exploring different options on how to install ChromiumOS on my desktop (x86_64) PC which is currently running Ubuntu 14.10. I tried the following methods first:

- Dual booting the two, but resizing or configuring Chromium OS partitions is a pain for me so there goes that option.
- I was thinking of running it within a chroot like in [this article on Make Tech Easier](http://www.maketecheasier.com/how-to-run-multiple-linux-distros-without-virtualization/) but that doesn't start a new X session.
- I tried "lightdm-login-chromeos" but that threw a few errors and
  looks pretty out of date (by like two years).

My question is whether or not there is a better, simpler and/or more efficient way of installing ChromiumOS on Ubuntu. If not, is how would I go about installing Chromium OS with any of the methods I tried above?

Comment: Outside of virtualization you can not run two OS at the same time. I suggest running chromium OS in KVM

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/running-chromeos-image-under-virtual-machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualization is the easiest way There are even virtual disk images prebuilt.

Install Virtualbox from the terminal with `sudo apt-get install virtualbox` or through the Software Center:

[image: vbox-softcenter]

Install Chromium OS on a VM under Virtualbox.

There are builds [here](http://chromium.arnoldthebat.co.uk/) and a step by step [installation.](http://calfaro.alfahar.com/chromium-os-installation-step-by-step/)

If something isn't clear drop me a comment and I'll expand the answer to sort it out.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I wanted to stay away from virtualization as far a possible.

Comment: Sorry, I got that impression from your question. I urge you to reconsider however. Correct me if I'm wrong but I personally have yet to see any indication that Chromium OS is stable enough to devote hardware to. The above appears to be the simplest way.